# How can I remove or hide an object on the model tree panel in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to hide (make it go away completely) from the model tree panel in Viewer.

I already tried overriding methods from the Viewer (some other stuff is done that way), but the Tree-related methods and objects are not accessible for extending. It also seems too dangerous to mess with instanceTree data, like removing the dbId from the nodes list.

I'm running on the latest Viewer code (6.5.3), and writing pure javascript extensions.

For example, I tried overriding this function, which is used internally to determine if a node should or not be displayed. It doesn't work, neither does overriding the same function on the ModelStructureTreeDelegate:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.UI.TreeDelegate.prototype.shouldCreateTreeNode = function (dbId)
{
    // original code on the viewer.js is:
    // return true;

    let itGo = true;

    // _objectsHiddenInTree is populated with dbIds of objects to be hidden right after initializing the viewer
    _objectsHiddenInTree.forEach(x => {
        if (x == dbId){
            itGo = false;
        }
    });

    // return false; doesn't work either

    return itGo;
};
```

Is there a way to do this from the Viewer side? I mean, to remove an item from the model tree?

If it's more viable, removing the object from the scene altogether is also a valid option. But I can't remove it from the model before sending to model derivative, it has to be done when opening the Viewer, or before opening the Tree Model panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally the easiest way would be to access node element via `viewer.modelstructure` and use styling to hide the node:

```
<style>
.yourHiddenNodeClass{display:none!important}
</style>
...
<script>
let modelStructureControl = viewer.modelstructure;
modelStructureControl.createUI(); //initialize the panel if it hasn't
let treeViewControl = modelStructureControl.tree;
let modelDelegate = treeViewControl.getDelegate(model.id);
treeViewControl.addClass(modelDelegate, dbid, "yourHiddenNodeClass", false) //hide a node - last boolean to toggle recursiveness
...
treeViewControl.removeClass(modelDeleagate, dbid, "yourHiddenNodeClass", false) //remove your custom class
</script>
```

And to hide a node completely:

```
model.visibilityManager.setNodeOff(dbid, true) // true=hide, false=show
```

Answer (score 0):

Bryan's answer gave me an idea that seems to work for now:

Every element on the tree panel has an atribute 'lmv-nodeid', with the dbId of the object. So I looked for it, and added the 'hidden' attribute to the div:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[lmv-nodeid="' + objectDbId + '"]')[0].hidden = true;
```

His answer is still better, though, because there is no guarantee that the attribute will remain on newer versions of the Viewer, whereas the Viewer classes and methods are more stable and future-proof.